# ASP.NET MVC Render View to PDF File and save on disk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm looking for a way to take a view in my MVC site and save it to a PDF and save it locally on disk. I have found a lot of answers that are similar to what I'm asking, but none of them actually answer it. How can I do this?

Comment: I do use the commercial [HiQPdf](http://www.hiqpdf.com/) library. See the [lots of online demos](http://www.hiqpdf.com/demo/ConvertHtmlToPdf.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [WkHtmlToPdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) before with good success.

It's a command line tool that you can install on your server.

Comment: does it save with all the css styles applied? and hide the elements that are hidden on print?

Comment: Yes.  It renders the URL you give it and then generates a PDF based on what is rendered.  Same as if you had a PDF Print driver installed and printed it locally to a pdf that way from the web browser...except this sits on your server.

Comment: do they have a nuget package? or i need to install something in my pc?

Comment: I found `Codaxy.WkHtmlToPdf` on nuget, but the Codazy prefix throws me off, don't know if it's a port or from the WkHtmlToPdf folks.

Comment: i tried Rotativa problem is that i don't see an option to save it on disk

Comment: @CMS wkhtmlToPdf is also good but i have not used this , as far as Rotativa is concerned you can save the pdf on disk. You would just render the view as a pdf and the pdf file would be automatically saved to your pc.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Rotativa, it worked great
[Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa/1.6.1)
The implementation is quite simple ,very few lines of code.
For example you would need just these lines to render view as a pdf

```
public ActionResult PrintInvoice(int invoiceId)
{
  return new ActionAsPdf(
                 "Invoice", 
                 new { invoiceId= invoiceId }) 
                 { FileName = "Invoice.pdf" };
}
```

For more info
[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335595/Rotativa-how-to-print-PDF-in-Asp-Net-MVC)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Aspose.pdf library (not free) for this in the past.

I believe this blog post here gives a very in-depth explanation of how to do it.

http://daveaglick.com/posts/using-aspnet-mvc-and-razor-to-generate-pdf-files